# What different non-bluetooth keyboards exist for the iPad 2?

Tags: keyboard, ipad, hardware-recommendation, accessories, lightning

I am in the navy, and am restricted in the use of RF emissions such as WiFi and Bluetooth.  Is there a keyboard I can use with my iPad 2 that will plug into the 30-pin connector?

Answer (score 1):

You'd want a wired keyboard such as this from [DealExtreme](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/78-key-compact-slim-wired-keyboard-for-ipad-iphone-3g-3gs-100cm-cable-44443). They ship to the US without any problems

[image: Wired keyboard]